# How to accept multiple vales from Botkit hears method?

Tags: javascript, regex, botkit

Code:

```
controller.hears([map (.*) (.*) into (.*)){
  var value = message.match[1];
        var source = message.match[2];
        var dest = message.match[3];   }
```

when input is `map 12 grams to kilograms` it works fine but when input is `map 12 square meter into square centimeter` then output is
`value = 12 square, source= meter and dest = square centimeter`

How to modify the code so that the value field accepts only number so that square meter goes to source field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
map (\d+) (.*) into (.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8r8fJf/1)

The first capturing group is now `(\d+)` and will only capture 1 or more digits.

You may also match 1+ whitespaces in between values using `\s+` (so, tabs and other whitespace will also be matched, 1 or more occurrences):

```
map\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+into\s+(.*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8r8fJf/2).

**Details**

- `map`  - a `map` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)`  - Group 1: one or more digits
- \s+
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible,
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `into` - `into` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much [Wiktor Stribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) after looking at (\d+) I was like how did I miss that thing.. Thanks for helping me out..